Array formula for extracting multiple rows from a table
I have a table, two columns, 1st column fill with A,B,C,D,...Z,  2nd column fill with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
I have to look up for some specific letters A,B,C,D and stack their corresponding values together and with my manual input, the result should look like 1,2,3,5,9
The shared sheet below should describe my situation clearly.
Here's my google sheet shared.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19YU21ZMv_fYWaiicxzp70CmFBogkpTJlhzFm7j-yqN4/edit?usp=sharing
I tried the formula involving BYROW(), VSTACK, QUERY, but that makes my sheet slow significantly, because my table is not just like the above sheet having 19 rows only. My table should have 4000+ rows.
Any idea to make it faster?
[EDIT] Base on the comments, i modified my formula to something below, it still takes me a few seconds to get the result. Would it be improve further?
=ArrayFormula(let(
x,offset('Table'!A2:V2,,,'Total Timetable'!$U$1),
y_1,offset(N78,,,$L$76),
y_2,offset(O78,,,$L$76),
y_3,offset(P78,,,$L$76),
y_4,offset(L78,,,$L$76)&offset(M78,,,$L$76),
MAP(
y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,LAMBDA(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,
JOIN("",SUBSTITUTE(SORT(VSTACK(if($F$7="D",{$G$5;$G$5+1},{$G$5}),IFNA(Filter(CHOOSECOLS(x,6),
CHOOSECOLS(x,19)=a_1,
CHOOSECOLS(x,2)=$A$2,
CHOOSECOLS(x,3)=$F$5,
REGEXMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(x,11),$G$2),
NOT(REGEXMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(x,5),$D$2)),
CHOOSECOLS(x,22)<>a_4,
CHOOSECOLS(x,13)=a_2,
CHOOSECOLS(x,18)=a_3),tocol(,1)))),"10","0")
)))))


Try filter() in place of query() and see if there's any improvement. Sometimes open-ended arrayformulas end up creating 50K+ rows(although data is in just 4K+ rows) which tend to slow down the sheet significantly.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Using Filter to Substitute for Query to Process Data
This answer is meant to cover all bases and to reinforce @rockinfreakshow's suggestion. This is an alternate solution you can use as a basis for your second formula and get you a real scenario comparison on your end since 4000 Rows data and 19 Rows data is really far apart. I am also assuming that the data is more complex than which will affect overall runtime for the formula.
Try this:
=LET(x,C2:D19, y, G2:H6, MAP(CHOOSECOLS(y,1), CHOOSECOLS(y,2),LAMBDA(r, a,IFNA(JOIN(",",SORT(VSTACK(a,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(x,2), CHOOSECOLS(x,1) = r)))),a))))

Sample Output:

Reference:
FILTER
MAP

I tried your suggestion and apply to my situation, it's faster than before, but i still need to wait for 1-3 seconds to have the result back. Would you please take a look on my formula, I edited to the main post. Thanks

I've looked at your shared Google Sheet. Let me help you optimize this lookup and stacking operation.
For your specific case where you want to:

Look up values for specific letters (A,B,C,D)
Combine them with a manual input (9)
Display them as a comma-separated list (1,2,3,5,9)

Here's a more efficient formula solution:
=JOIN(",",{VLOOKUP({"A";"B";"C";"D"},A2:B,2,FALSE);9})

This approach is better because:

VLOOKUP is generally faster than QUERY

JOIN is more efficient than array manipulation functions

We avoid using BYROW which can be resource-intensive on large datasets

The curly brackets {} create a simple array without complex operations
=JOIN(",",FILTER(B2:B,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"^[A-D]$"))&",9")


Both these formulas should perform significantly better than using BYROW, VSTACK, and QUERY combinations, especially with 4000+ rows of data.
Key benefits:

Reduced computational complexity
No array processing overhead
Direct lookup instead of querying
Single-pass operation

Choose the first formula if your lookup letters are fixed (A,B,C,D) or the second formula if you need more flexibility in which letters to match.

Sorry, my question is a simplified version, vlookup allows me to search One criteria only, but my table actually has 10+ columns, I have to search something like Columns 1 "=A" , Column 2 "=b", Column 3 "=..." etc, after this searching process, it will gives a few rows of the data, that's why i use query instead of vlookup

What if you try a non-lambda solution:
=ArrayFormula(LET(rowSize,IFERROR(MATCH(,0/(A:A<>""))-1,0),
              lookupCol,OFFSET(A1,1,0,rowSize),
              returnCol,OFFSET(B1,1,0,rowSize),
              searchKeys,D2:D6,
              numInsert,E2:E6,
              lookupCol__insert,VSTACK(lookupCol,searchKeys),
              returnCol__insert,VSTACK(returnCol,numInsert),
              filterKeysCond,"'"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,searchKeys)&"'",
              data,HSTACK(lookupCol__insert,returnCol__insert,returnCol__insert),
              summary,QUERY(data,"SELECT MIN(Col2) WHERE Col1 MATCHES "&filterKeysCond&" GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1 LABEL MIN(Col2) ''",0),
              summary_data,REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(summary,"OFFSET 1",0),,9^9))," ",","),
              summary_header,TRIM(CHOOSEROWS(summary,1)),
              final,XLOOKUP(searchKeys,summary_header,summary_data),
              final))


Make sure to change the references to your situation. Let me know if this will improve your speed.

Thanks for another comment, I studied your suggestion. It works again with just one filterkeyCond. You can see that in my main post (the question). I have to filter the table with a few columns, the variable i used are y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4 which is then "Loop" through all elements with the function MAP. I may make another column for the table so that it TEXTJOIN all the filter conditions to one column then use your suggestion.

Please provide an example data with your extra columns for the filter conditions.
